# boost::spirit::real_p some how round ups the value

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

I am using the boost::spirit parser. At one point when I use real_p, the value coming out of the parser stack is 38672000 instead of the actual value, 386731500. Some how it is considering it as a float value, I think. Is there anyway to fix this? Do I need to set the precision of real_p, or am using real_p in the wrong context?

Comment: Please add some code reproducing your problem, otherwise I'm not able to help/fix the issue. Generally, the real_p parser is not supposed to behave the way you're describing things and we've never got a similar issue report for Spirit.Classic before. Does the same problem persist if you use Spirit V2.x?